# Looking for a Short Story on time travel origin of Thor legend

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I once read and am trying to find a short story of a man from ~1970 who is transported back to ancient Scandinavia. Here he integrates with a band of Norse hunters who then get in a fight with foes. His use of a .45 Auto and subsequent disappearance creates the legend of Thor and his hammer.

Can anyone help me with the author, title and where to find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help Identify Viking Time Travel Short Story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38243/help-identify-viking-time-travel-short-story)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open for now, as it doesn't meet the criteria for "accepted answer", as per [Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/21267)

Answer (score 7):

"[Frost and Thunder](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46221)" by Randall Garrett in the anthology *Time Wars* as per [Help Identify Viking Time Travel Short Story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38243/help-identify-viking-time-travel-short-story?rq=1).

> My weapon has a name now, as Sten suggested. I looked up a man who
> knows Norse runes, and I had another man engrave those runes on my
> pistol, on the right, just above the trigger.
>
> The engraving says: Mjolnir.
>
> Yah.
>
> The original.

Comment: Doesn't that make the question a duplicate?

Comment: @can-ned_food Not unless the OP accepts or says that it is what they were looking for. See [Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/21267) for details.